# WooCommerce: Building a page with user input which is used to query order status and external API and return a result

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I don't know where to start in terms of building a plugin, some php or how to go about my project for my woocommerce store:

**Feature overview:**

1. User inputs Order ID
2. Order ID queries WooCommerce API to get order status as well as custom fields from that order
3. Result from custom field is used to query external API
4. Result of WooCommerce API query (Order Status) as well as external API based on return of custom fields is displayed on a page

What is my best approach? Frontend html for user input, php for queries and html again for display?

Thanks